# select rows from a table where the date column has a date less than or equal to a given date

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id person_id element_name element_value element_effective_date
1   123          a                 25             07/01/16
2   123          b                100             05/01/16
3   123          a                 25             07/20/16
4   456          b                101             01/01/16
5   456          b                102             04/01/16
6   456          a                 25             08/01/16
7   789          b                101             08/01/16
8   789          c                200             07/25/16
9   789          d                201             07/26/16
```

I want to select the person_ids from the table for a selected element_name where the element_value is equal to some value and the rows' effective date is equal to a given date or is the first row for the person_id with the effective date less than the given date.

For example, if the element_name = a and the element_value = 25 and the given date is 8/5/2016 then the rows selected would be 6 and 3. If the given date changes to 7/25/2016, then the selected row would be 3. If the given date changes to 7/15/2016, then the selected row would be 1.

Comment: Your life would be easier if you stored your dates in ISO format instead of the (insane) American format. Your life would be *much* easier if the datatype of date column was `date` instead of `text`. I recommend addressing one of these issues first, then you wouldn't have to ask this question.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Many products have their own, non-ANSI, functions for date/time.)

Comment: Also add the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE element_name = @element_name 
  AND element_value = @element_value 
  AND element_effective_date < @element_effective_date
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I do not think it works. Using the first example the result would be rows 1, 3, and 6. Rows 1 and 3 are associated with person_id = 123. I want just rows 3 and 6 returned - only one row max per person_id.

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Answer (score 0):

your problem was not that clear, anyway if i understood your problem correctly, below is the solution

```
declare @element_name varchar(1)= 'a'
declare @element_value int = 25
declare @element_effective_date smalldatetime ='7/15/2016' 
--'7/25/2016' 
--'8/5/2016'

create table #a(
id int,
person_id int,
element_name varchar(1),
element_value int,
element_effective_date smalldatetime)

insert into #a
select 1, 123, 'a',  25,'07/01/2016' union
select 2, 123, 'b', 100,'05/01/2016' union
select 3, 123, 'a',  25,'07/20/2016' union
select 4, 456, 'b', 101,'01/01/2016' union
select 5, 456, 'b', 102,'04/01/2016' union
select 6, 456, 'a',  25,'08/01/2016' union
select 7, 789, 'b', 101,'08/01/2016' union
select 8, 789, 'c', 200,'07/25/2016' union
select 9, 789, 'd', 201,'07/26/2016' 



select * 
Into #solutionDataset
from #a 
where element_name=@element_name
and element_value=@element_value
and element_effective_date < @element_effective_date

/*
I want to select the person_ids from the table for a selected element_name where the element_value is equal to some value and the rows' effective date is equal to a given date or is the first row for the person_id with the effective date less than the given date.
*/
if(@@ROWCOUNT=1)
begin
select * from #solutionDataset
end

else 
begin
    select * from #solutionDataset
    where id not in(select min(id) from #a where element_name=@element_name and element_value=@element_value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure I follow all the logic you intended but these ought to be pretty close. I'm also assuming SQL Server but that should only matter for the parameter names.

If you can guarantee that the `id` values are increasing:

```
select *
from <T>
where id in (
    select max(id)
    from <T>
    where element_value = @element_value and element_effective_date <= @effective_date
    group by person_id
)
```

If not but you can still guarantee no ties on `effective_date`:

```
select t.*
from
    <T> t
    inner join
    (
        select person_id, element_value, max(element_effective_date) as max_date
        from <T>
        where element_effective_date <= @effective_date
        group by person_id
    ) as m
        on     m.person_id = t.person_id
           and m.element_value = t.element_value
           and m.max_date = t.element_effective_date
where
    t.element_value = @element_value
```

Answer (score -1):

Store data as YYYYMMDD and then use this statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE element_value = @value
AND element_name = @name
AND element_effective_date <= @date
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
select person_id
from
(
    select max(element_effective_date), person_id
    from
    (
        select t.person_id, t.element_effective_date
        from table t
        where t.element_name = 'a' and t.element_value = 25
          and t.element_effective_date <= '2016-08-05'
    ) as foo
    group by person_id
);
```

thx for your comments.

Comment: That query is unnecessarily complicated if all you want is the personid.

Comment: Actually I'm not the downvoter. Here's a simpler query `select distinct t.person_id from <T> t where t.element_name = 'a' and t.element_value = 25 and t.element_effective_date <= '2016-08-05'`